# OpenStack Keystone Identity Service Httpd Failed (rocky version)

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone

Hello and thanks for taking some of your time to check my problem
i'm following the detailed steps by openstack to install openstack in no avail (https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/rocky/install/keystone-install-rdo.html)
I've tried to change the 5000 port for the service but the result is the same
any insights are most welcomed

```
[root@localhost i-openstack]# systemctl enable httpd.service
[root@localhost i-openstack]# systemctl start httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@localhost i-openstack]# journalctl -xe
Oct 08 05:12:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Oct 08 05:12:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Oct 08 05:12:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Oct 08 05:12:39 localhost.localdomain polkitd[1824]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:4229:106865 (system bus name :1.42, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Oct 08 05:27:21 localhost.localdomain polkitd[1824]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:4930:195069 (system bus name :1.43 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale
Oct 08 05:27:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Reloading.
Oct 08 05:27:21 localhost.localdomain polkitd[1824]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:4930:195069 (system bus name :1.43, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain polkitd[1824]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:4950:195568 (system bus name :1.44 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain httpd[4956]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:5000
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain httpd[4956]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:5000
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain httpd[4956]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain httpd[4956]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain kill[4958]: kill: cannot find process ""
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Oct 08 05:27:26 localhost.localdomain polkitd[1824]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:4950:195568 (system bus name :1.44, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Oct 08 05:34:01 localhost.localdomain polkitd[1824]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:5222:235020 (system bus name :1.45 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale
Oct 08 05:34:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Reloading.
Oct 08 05:34:01 localhost.localdomain polkitd[1824]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:5222:235020 (system bus name :1.45, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Oct 08 05:34:03 localhost.localdomain polkitd[1824]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:5240:235248 (system bus name :1.46 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale
Oct 08 05:34:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION : It seemed i had to disable SELinux

Disable temporaliy

> sudo setenforce 0

Restart httpd service

> service httpd restart

Disable SELinux persistently (reboot required)

> nano /etc/selinux/config
>
> SELINUX=disabled